# homebrew clang and c++11 error: no member named 'cbegin' in 'std::basic_string<char>'

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

[edit2]

Since the answers in the above questions did not help me solve my problem fully, I would like to add this:

When using clang from Homebrew `-stdlib=libc++` did not work for me. I't could not be found from Hombrew clang. My solution was to build libc++ according to instructions on their web page. And then use `clang++ -I/path/to/libcxx/include -L/path/to/libcxx/lib` after exporting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, also from instructions on libc++ web page.

[/edit2]

[edit]

Looking at the first few comments I see I have an error. But string::const_iterator gives the same error.

```
error: no member named 'cbegin' in
      'std::basic_string<char>'
    for ( string::const_iterator it = line.cbegin();
```

[/edit]

I am trying to compile the folowing code using -std=c++11. I am using clang 3.2 via homebrew and I am getting the error in the title.

```
vector<string> extractWords( const string& line ) {
    string tmp;
    vector<string> words;
    int colonCount = 0;

    for ( string::iterator it = line.cbegin();
            it != line.end(); ++it ) {
        if ( isprint( *it ) && !isspace( *it ) ) {
        }
    }
...
    return words;
}
```

Shouldn't this work with c++11?

(sorry about the accidental deletion of the post)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you want to split a string into words on space boundary, I recommend using `std::istringstream` and the normal input `>>` operator.

Comment: @juanchopanza No, it's the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149835/on-os-x-simple-c-program-gives-incorrect-results-which-are-a-result-of-comma/14150421#14150421 is another one, still due to not using `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: @JonathanWakely same issue, same solution, but different question. I see your point though.

Comment: I think I'll edit the [tag:clang] tag wiki with this issue

Comment: We can use?: for (char c : line) if (isprint(c)...  ?

Comment: @juanchopanza, different question, but I'm not going to give the same answer for every single C++11 library component that isn't supported by libstdc++ 4.2 :)

Comment: using -stdlib=libc++ gives me fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream> =(

Comment: Do you have libc++ installed? There are some instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14873511/981959

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14115349/981959 also seems to be relevant